# Datepicker in widget

Tags: widgets, date

What is the best way to create widget with a parameter with date picker?

The problem is that I did not find a good way to supply format value to Date element class.

Comment: Do you mean a date to be entered in the admin section of the widget or the front end?

Comment: When you choose a widget, a date needs to be selected as widget parameter. So, in admin section, yes.

Comment: Can you please explain a little bit more, what you are talking about? Maybe add a screenshot.

Comment: Sure: http://postimg.org/image/e31ldikmj/. Below "Block* Not selected", I want "Date:" and datepicker.

Answer (score 3):

Date fields don't work in widgets mainly because of this: `Mage_Widget_Block_Adminhtml_Widget_Options::_addField()` - this is the method that renders the options.
The date for the widget option looks like this:

```
    $data = array(
        'name'      => $form->addSuffixToName($fieldName, 'parameters'),
        'label'     => $this->_translationHelper->__($parameter->getLabel()),
        'required'  => $parameter->getRequired(),
        'class'     => 'widget-option',
        'note'      => $this->_translationHelper->__($parameter->getDescription()),
    );
```

So even if you specify a format in your xml it will be ignored.
Rewrite the method above and add change the code above to:

```
    $data = array(
        'name'      => $form->addSuffixToName($fieldName, 'parameters'),
        'label'     => $this->_translationHelper->__($parameter->getLabel()),
        'required'  => $parameter->getRequired(),
        'class'     => 'widget-option',
        'note'      => $this->_translationHelper->__($parameter->getDescription()),

    );
    if ($parameter->getType() == 'date') {
        'format'    => $parameter->getFormat(),
        'image'     => $this->getSkinUrl('images/grid-cal.gif'),
    }
```

And this still won't get it to work. I mean the field will appear but the calendar doesn't work. I haven't figured out yet why.

Comment: @LDusan. No problem. Sorry I couldn't give you a 100% working solution.

Answer (score 2):

I inserted the datepicker with little trick:

Inside widget.xml:

```
        <to_date>
            <label>Date</label>
            <visible>1</visible>
            <required>1</required>  
            <type>text</type>                        
            <helper_block>
                <type>Namespace_Module_Block_Adminhtml_Widget_Date</type>
            </helper_block>              
        </to_date>
```

Block file:

```
class Namespace_Module_Block_Adminhtml_Widget_Date extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid
{

    public function __construct($arguments=array())
    {
        parent::__construct($arguments);
    } 

    public function prepareElementHtml(Varien_Data_Form_Element_Abstract $element)
    {  
       //var_dump($this->getSkinUrl('images/grid-cal.gif')); exit;
       $form = new Varien_Data_Form(array(
            'id'        => 'edit_form',
            'action'    => '',
            'method'    => 'post'
        ));
        $element2 = new Varien_Data_Form_Element_Date(
            array(
                'name' => 'date',
                'label' => Mage::helper('module')->__('Date'),
                'after_element_html' => '<small>Click icon to select</small>',
                'tabindex' => 1,
                'type'  => 'datetime',
                'time'=>true,
                'image' => $this->getSkinUrl('images/grid-cal.gif'),
                'format' => 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss',
                'value' => date(
                    'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss',
                    strtotime('next weekday')
                )
            )
        );    

        $element2->setForm($form);
        $id = 'date'.$element->getHtmlId();
        $element2->setId($id);
        $html = $element2->getElementHtml();    
        $html .= "
        <style>
        .calendar{z-index:999999;}
        #$id{display:none}
        </style>
        <script>     
        var element = jQuery('#".$element->getHtmlId()."');
        element.attr('style', 'width: 150px !important');
        jQuery('body').on('change', '#$id', function(e) {
            element.val(jQuery(this).val())
        });          
        jQuery('#{$id}_trig').on('click', function() {                                       
          setTimeout(function(){                            
          jQuery('.calendar').css('top',(parseInt(element.offset().top)-50)+'px')
          jQuery('.calendar').css('left',(parseInt(element.offset().left)-150)+'px')      
          }, 100);   
        });    
        </script>";    

        $element->setData('after_element_html', $html);
        return $element;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply add following code to your widget ....

Namespace/Module/etc/widget.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<widgets>
<namespacemodule type="core/template" translate="name description">
    <from_date>
        <label>Date</label>
        <visible>1</visible>
        <required>1</required>
        <type>date</type>
        <helper_block>
            <type>namespacemodule/adminhtml_widget_date</type>
        </helper_block>
    </from_date>
    ...
```

Namespace/Module/Block/Adminhtml/Widget/Date.php

```
<?php

class Namespace_Module_Block_Adminhtml_Widget_Date extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid {
    public function __construct($arguments = array()) {
        parent::__construct($arguments);
    }

    public function prepareElementHtml(Varien_Data_Form_Element_Abstract $element) {
        $element->setFormat('yyyy-MM-dd');
        $element->setImage($this->getSkinUrl('images/grid-cal.gif'));
        return $element;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In Magento 2 it works in this way

Namespace/Module/etc/widget.xml:

```
<parameter name="display_from" xsi:type="block" required="true" visible="true" sort_order="40">
    <label translate="true">Display from</label>
    <block class="Namespace\Module\Block\Widget\Type\DatePicker">
    </block>
</parameter>
```

Namespace/Module/Block/Widget/Type/DatePicker.php:

```
<?php
namespace Namespace\Module\Block\Widget\Type;
use Magento\Backend\Block\{
    Template,
    Template\Context,
};
use Magento\Framework\Data\Form\{
    Element\AbstractElement,
    Element\Factory,
};
use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;

class DatePicker extends Template
{

/**
 * @var Factory
 */
private $elementFactory;

/**
 * DatePicker constructor.
 *
 * @param Context $context
 * @param Factory $elementFactory
 * @param array   $data
 */
public function __construct(
    Context $context,
    Factory $elementFactory,
    $data = []
) {
    $this->elementFactory = $elementFactory;
    parent::__construct($context, $data);
}

/**
 * @param AbstractElement $element
 *
 * @return AbstractElement
 * @throws LocalizedException
 */
public function prepareElementHtml(AbstractElement $element): AbstractElement
{
    /** @var \Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\Text $input */
    $input = $this->elementFactory->create("text", ['data' => $element->getData()]);
    $input->setId($element->getId());
    $input->setForm($element->getForm());
    $input->addCustomAttribute('style', 'width: auto');
    $input->setClass('widget-option input-text admin__control-text');
    if ($element->getRequired()) {
        $input->addClass('required-entry');
    }

    $calendarScript = '
        <script>require([
            "jquery",
            "mage/translate",
            "mage/calendar"
            ], function ($, $t) {
              $("#' . $element->getId() . '").calendar({
                changeMonth: true,
                changeYear: true,
                showButtonPanel: true,
                currentText: $t("Go Today"),
                closeText: $t("Close")
              });
            })</script>';
    $element->setData('after_element_html', $input->getElementHtml() . $calendarScript);
    $element->setValue('');

    return $element;
}
}
```

You can get data of this parameter in your Blocks in this way:

`$this->getData('display_from')`

Datepicker looks like:
[image]

Comment: This works from the Content > Widgets Admin forms, but not when inserting a Widget into a CMS Page via de Admin. Then the Date fields are simply text fields. I'm now trying to figure out how to use it there too